# How do I pass a powershell argument to a non powershell command?

Tags: powershell

I runing the following simple powershell command on a remote server. However I need to pass a variable to the `NET LOCALGROUP` command:

```
$serverName = "SCO32"
$groupName = "SCO33_Local_Admins"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName 

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {

$args[1]
$args[0]

net localgroup administrators domainname\$args[1] /ADD

} -ArgumentList $serverName, $groupName
```

The arguments are passing correctly as is the remote connection, it just doesn't seem to be able to execute the command because it's trying to use the $args[1] as a literal and not domainname\SCO33_Local_Admins

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use [this script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-AD-UserGroup-to-Local-fe5e9239#content) that already does exactly what you want to do?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - thanks for the link, but this is part of something bigger, and I want to learn at the same time.  Thanks.

Comment: I recommend using ADSI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$servername = 'sv1'
```

In v2:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { 
   param($servername, $group)
  net localgroup administrators domainname\$servername /ADD 
} -ArgumentList $serverName, $groupName
```

Or in v3

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { 
  net localgroup administrators domainname\${using:servername} /ADD 
}
```

Or:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
  net localgroup administrators domainname\$($args[1]) /ADD 
} -ArgumentList $serverName, $groupName
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in a function or in a script you can assign parameters to a scriptblock. While using the automatic $args may not work for you, you can do this:

```
$serverName = "SCO32"
$groupName = "SCO33_Local_Admins"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName 

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
Param($SrvName,$GrpName)
net localgroup administrators domainname\$GrpName /ADD

} -ArgumentList $serverName, $groupName
```